# Bare bones Message example needed, from AsyncTask to UI thread, not using Services

Tags: android

I am looking for simple example code for setting up a Message in an AsyncTask and handling it in the Handler in the UI thread.

The examples I've seen deal with this inside a Service, and my app is not currently using any Services. Can a Message be used without a Service?

Example code would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final int MSG = 1;
private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch( msg.what ){
            case MSG:{

            }break;
        }
    }
}; 


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     new YourAST(handler).execute();
}


public class YourAST extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    Handler mHandler = null;

    public YourAST(Handler handler){
         this.mHandler = handler;
    } 

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg) {

        // send message to UIthread
        if(mHandler!=null)
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(YourClass.MSG);

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around on your answer.

Comment: After evaluating your answer, I realized that I have asked for the wrong thing.

What I really need to do is to be able to send a Message to the UI from inside another thread. The other thread will be running because I've received an unsolicited UDP packet in another thread and I need to send some of that received data to the UI.

Can you provide example code showing how to send a Message from another thread to the UI?

Comment: You would want to do this exactly the same way. Have the handler in your UI thread, in w/e class is housing your second thread have it have a setHandler() thread, when you initialize your UI have it pass its handler to that class. In that class have a sender function that checks if the handler is null, if its not null(UI is visable) send the message. Let me know if you need a detailed example.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback. This was very helpful! I've got it up and running now.